# Very large vendor.xxxx.js.map

Tags: vue.js

I've got a Vue.js 2.0 project set up with vue-cli. When I do a build, with 'npm run build', I notice that a very large (typically 3Mb or so) file called something like 'static/js/vendor.b8e29cb5ed3515116b61.js.map' is created. I was just wondering what this is and is it something which is downloaded to the browser, in which case that's quite an impact. If so, is there some way I can prevent it or reduce the size.

Comment: It's a source map. The build process compresses your source code, making it unreadable to humans. A source map allows the browser to link the compressed code to your source code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315460/when-do-browsers-download-sourcemaps

Comment: From the question linked, it appears it's only downloaded if developer tools or similar is opened, in which case the size is not an issue,