# How google chrome debugs typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I have some angular applications which I did built using angular CLI which has typescript files. I always did debugged them from chrome, but chrome only understands javascript, right? Does anyone know how it manages to debug typescript?

Comment: the angular cli compiles your app to js files and serves it then... when you see where the console.logs or errors or whatever come from, it's due to generated sourcemap files

Comment: write the **debugger** in code, where you want to check.

Comment: Short answer, sourcemaps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315460/when-do-browsers-download-sourcemaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Angluar with VS Code then you can use [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) extension to debug typescript in Chrome or any other target that supports the Chrome DevTools Protocol.